# Swift Message Box

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

how to add message box in Swift and make it compatible with IOS 7 +

I have the following code which works with IOS 8:

```
 var alert = UIAlertController(title: "hello world", message:
            "DO YOU WANT TO PLAY", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
      handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler:
  {action in      
   // CODE
}))
```

and I have the following code which works with IOS 7 + (I don't know how to respond to the button click):

```
    var alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "HelloWorld"
    alert.message = "DO YOU WANT TO PLAY"
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Yes")
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("No")
    alert.show()
```

How to modify either of these codes and make it fully work?

Comment: `UIAlerView` in iOS7 and `UIAlertController` in iOS8.

Comment: Write you version, if it doesn't work come back with it and get help. SO is not a code writing service, we're to help with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your class conform to the 'UIAlertViewDelegate' protocol and implement this method:

```
func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
       //Do something
    }
}
```

There you can handle any user interaction with your alertview.
You can determine which button was tapped by the user by checking the buttonIndex variable.

This will work in iOS 7 and 8